# Blogger API - How to add labels while inserting a new post?

Tags: api, label, blogger

I am trying to insert new blog post with Blogger API v3.0 below is my sample payload

```
var payload = {
  "title"   : "This is the post title2",
  "content" : "This is <b>HTML</b> post2"
};
```

this works as intended, but I need to insert labels while posting these new posts, I checked the documentation and Google but no help. I tried something like below

```
var payload = {
  "title"   : "This is the post title2",
  "content" : "This is <b>HTML</b> post2",
  "labels"  : "test_post,test,post"
};
```

based on a v1.0 php example, still I was not successful.

Comment: When you are building a new application, I encourage you to use the latest API version, v3. v1 is deprecated.

Comment: Hi @paolo I am using API V3.0, Sorry if I am not clear above.

Comment: My fault, actually. I overlooked your first line. I was relating to the last line. Did my answer bring any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Post Resource documentation](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts#resource) states that the `labels` attribute is a list. Your payload should probably look like this:

```
var payload = {
  "title"   : "This is the post title2",
  "content" : "This is <b>HTML</b> post2",
  "labels"  : [
                "test_post",
                "test",
                "post"
              ]
};
```

Comment: Thank you @paolo , will try once I back to home.

Comment: Working fine :) Thank you @paolo